# missing values in R does not allow to calculate the conditional mean

Tags: r

For this dataset:

```
index    age   gender
1        10      F
2        NA      M
3        20      F
4        30      NA
6        40      M
7        30      M
```

I am trying to calculate the mean of age for just Female (F). As you see both columns have NA values. This is my code:

```
mean(age [gender == "F"], na.rm=TRUE)
```

But it returns NA. I also tried the following to remove NA from gender column, but no result: gender = (gender, na.rm = TRUE) .

Any suggestion ?

Comment: `with(dataset, mean(age[gender == "F"], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: You have to specify `x$age` and `x$gender` in base R, unless you use `with()` as shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work OK for me

```
x <- read.table(text="
    index    age   gender
    1        10      F
    2        NA      M
    3        20      F
    4        30      NA
    6        40      M
    7        30      M", header=TRUE)

mean(x$age[x$gender == "F"], na.rm=TRUE)
# 15
```

A few suggestions though.

- `F` isn't quite a reserved word, but it's by default an alias for `FALSE` and hence probably best to leave like that, in the interest of readability.
- Use `str()` on the data frame you are processing, do the first two columns show up as `numeric` or `integer`?
- An alternate method for summarizing by a factor is to use `aggregate()`

```
aggregate(age ~ gender, data=x, mean)
#   gender age
# 1      F  15
# 2      M  35
```